# How to notify duplicate value is posted in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using mongodb(with monk api) and expressjs. 
In my code I wrote

```
router.post("/",function(req, res) {
    var collection = db.get("details");
    collection.insert({ id: req.body.id, data: req.body.data }, 
                        function(err, details) {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            res.json(details);
                        })
});
```

'id' field is set to unique. If any duplicate 'id' is entered, then I want to notify it to the frontend. How to di it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `count` to find if that `id` already exists:

```
collection.count({id : req.body.id},function(err,count){
    if(!err){
        if(count>0){
            //send the response that its duplicate.
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the mongoose schema : unique true will give you the error on duplicate insertion.

```
 { require: true, unique: true },
```